# How do I disable a touchpad using the command line?

Tags: command-line, touchpad

Is there a way to disable a touchpad using a terminal command?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

To turn off touch pad:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=1
```

To turn it back on:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=0
```

Comment: Simple but go to the point.

Comment: does not work on my computer...

Comment: Interesting, good to know.

Comment: The command ran without error on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on Dell XPS 13 but had no effect.

Comment: Toggle would be nice -- I would like to set it up as a short cut or something. Better yet, when it's docked, I want the touchpad off

Comment: best answer for me. Finally there's no more need  touchpad indicator :).

Comment: This disabled moving around but not tapping to click. Is there a way to completely disable the touchpad?

Answer (score 30):

There are at least two methods (that I know of) you could try.

### synclient

If your laptop is equipped with a Synaptics (or ALPS) touchpad you can indeed use `synclient` as already mentioned by Shutupsquare. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and on my machine it was installed by default.

Test if synclient is installed: `synclient -V` (it should report the version number)

Turn touchpad ON: `synclient TouchpadOff=0`

Turn touchpad OFF: `synclient TouchpadOff=1`

I have not tested this myself, but if your goal is to not move the mouse when your arms are resting on the touch pad, this might help.

Turn palm detection ON: `synclient PalmDetect=1`

Turn palm detection OFF: `synclient PalmDetect=0`

In general you can configure any property of your Synaptics touchpad by `synclient property=value`. Where the property is one of the available properties shown by `synclient -l`

#### Links for further reading

[ubuntu - comminity help wiki - SynapticsTouchpad](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad)

archlinux - wiki - Touchpad Synaptics

ask ubuntu - How do I make my synclient settings stick? - Ubuntu

### xinput

If you do not want or cannot use synclient, you could also use `xinput`. The procedure is somewhat similar.

list all xinput devices: `xinput`

Part of the ouput could look like this:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse           id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

It this particular case my touchpad has id=17 and its full name is "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad".

The command to set a property is `xinput set-prop`. The property to enable or disable the touchpad is `Device Enabled`, so to enable or disable it type:

Turn touchpad ON: `xinput set-prop <id> "Device Enabled" 1` (where `<id>` is your device id, in my case 17)

Turn touchpad OFF: `xinput set-prop <id> "Device Enabled" 0`

Turn palm detection ON: `xinput set-prop <id> "Palm Detection" 1`

Turn palm detection OFF: `xinput set-prop <id> "Palm Detection" 0`

To query available properties: `xinput list-props <id>` OR `xinput list-props <full-name>`, this should be quite similair to `synclient -l`.

#### Links for further reading

[ubuntu - wiki - input](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Input)

### NOTE

When setting properties through either `xinput` or `synclient` the properties are not set to the other tool. They are also not set in unity-control-center.

Comment: Thanks for the second answer. `synclient` didn't work for me, `xinput` did.

Comment: Note that `xinput` ids can change over restarts. So relying on these ids in scripts or shortcuts won't work.

Comment: `synclient` totally works on Arch Linux. Thank you *so* much!!!

Comment: This did it for me. In particular, I discovered I need to run `xinput <enable/disable> <id>`, as setting `TouchpadOff` via `synclient` was ineffective.

Comment: Thank you for the introduction to `xinput`. I was in a bit of a pickle with my builtin keyboard and trackpoint buttons apparently sending bad inputs that interfered with the input from the external keyboard. This allowed my to disable the builtin devices. Cheers! :)

Comment: All one command:   xinput list | sed '/Touch[Pp]ad/!d; s/.*id=//;s/\s.*//' | xargs -i xinput --disable {}

Answer (score 8):

`synclient` and `xinput` will not work if you are using gnome (or unity, cinnamon) environment, because it will override settings, so if you want `synclient` or `xinput` to take over these settings, you should disable that first:

1. install `dconf-editor` if not installed:

   ```
   apt-get install dconf-editor
   ```
2. run `dconf-editor`

   ```
   dconf-editor
   ```
3. open the directory `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/mouse/` or `/org/cinnamon/settings-daemon/plugins/mouse/`, and unclick the checkbox for `active`.
4. `logout` or `reboot`

This should make `synclient` or `xinput` work.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a python piece of code (now updated from python2 to python3) so that you can use the `xinput` technique without doing all the manual work.  Copyleft, AS-IS, no warranty, use at your own risk.  Works great for me:  and if you are using gnome, just map it to a key shortcut like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''Program to toggle Touchpad Enable to Disable or vice-versa.'''

from subprocess import check_output
import re


def current_id():
    """ Search through the output of xinput and find the line that has the
    word Touchpad.  At that point, I believe we can find the ID of that device.
    """

    props = check_output(["xinput"]).decode("utf-8").splitlines()
    match = [line for line in props if "Touchpad" in line]
    assert len(match) == 1, "Problem finding Touchpad string! %s" % match

    pat = re.match(r"(.*)id=(\d+)", match[0])
    assert pat, "No matching ID found!"

    return int(pat.group(2))


def current_status(tpad_id):
    """Find the current Device ID
        - it has to have the word Touchpad in the line."""

    props = check_output(
        ['xinput','list-props',str(tpad_id)]).decode("utf-8").splitlines()
    match = [line for line in props if "Device Enabled" in line]
    assert len(match) == 1, "Can't find the status of device #%d" % tpad_id

    pat = re.match(r"(.*):\s*(\d+)", match[0])
    assert pat, "No matching status found!"
    return int(pat.group(2))

def flop(tpad_id, status):
    """Change the value of status, and call xinput to reverse that status."""
    if status == 0:
        status = 1
    else:
        status = 0

    print("Changing Device #",tpad_id," Device Enabled to ",status)
    props = check_output(['xinput',
                          'set-prop',
                          str(tpad_id),
                          'Device Enabled',
                          str(status)])

def main():
    """Get curent device id and status, and flop status value."""
    tpad = current_id()
    stat = current_status(tpad)
    flop(tpad, stat)

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

1. List your input devices:

   ```
   xinput list
   ```

   In my case I have this list:

   ```
   Virtual core XTEST pointer                  id=4
   Logitech M510                               id=11   
   ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                    id=15
   ```
2. Disable your touchpad by passing the ID

   ```
   xinput set-prop 15 "Device Enabled" 0
   ```

Comment: When typing manually, you can use `xinput enable [device]` and `xinput disable [device]` directly. When scripting though, using `set-prop [device] "Device Enabled" [value]` may be a bit easier, as in World Python Developer's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Disable any touchpad in a single command, good for a script.

```
xinput list |
  sed '/Touch[Pp]ad/!d; s/.*id=//;s/\s.*//' |
    xargs -i xinput --disable {}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Gnome, my function key to toggle the touchpad was not working for some reason, so I made a script using gsettings.

- Advantage: not vendor-specific
- Disadvantage: on Gnome, the touchpad clicks (not tap) are still handled for some reason, whereas the `xinput` solution completely deactivates the touchpad as expected. If like me, your only problem is that you are inadvertently moving the cursor while typing, though, that will be enough.

`toggle_touchpad_gsettings.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
import sys
import subprocess

gsettings_schema, gsettings_key = "org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad", "send-events"

def get_touchpad_send_events():
    send_events_value = subprocess.check_output(["gsettings", "get", gsettings_schema, gsettings_key])
    return send_events_value.strip()

def toggle_touchpad():
    # string returned from get is a repr including quotes,
    # but string sent with set does not need to have quotes
    if get_touchpad_send_events() == b"'enabled'":
        newval = 'disabled'
    else:
        newval = 'enabled'
    subprocess.Popen(["gsettings", "set", gsettings_schema, gsettings_key, newval])
    print(f"Set {gsettings_schema}:{gsettings_key} to {newval}")

def main():
    toggle_touchpad()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It should also work on Unity, but I haven't tested.