# How do I disable the touchpad while typing?

Tags: touchpad

It's impossible to write this way, text gets deleted, windows change, random tabs open. I've tried every solution I came across but none actually solve it (some don't even work)

I've tried installing touchpad indicator, I've tried adding a syndaemon option from startup application, I tried the same but from the terminal, nothing works.

I Just want to disable the touchpad completely while typing, no scrolling, no moving the cursor, nothing.

Comment: It is very easy. Run `xinput disable <ID>`. The ID you can find by `xinput` command. But I suggest installing `libinput`, it should solve the issues.

Comment: @pilot6 

Sorry, I meant to say I Want to disable it only while typing, not all the time.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: @Pilot6 16.04.1

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/773595/ https://askubuntu.com/questions/462135/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I suggest installing `libinput` it has much better "disable while typing" and "palm detection" algorithms.

Run

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-libinput
```

and restart the GUI session, or reboot.

If you need "tap to click", you can add

```
Option "Tapping" "true"
```

to the touchpad section of `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-libinput.conf`.

All options can be found on the [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man4/libinput.4.html).

If you are using Ubuntu 16.04 with the `-hwe-16.94` stack, you will need to install `xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-16.04` package instead of `xserver-xorg-input-libinput`.

You can check which HWE stack is installed by checking if `xserver-xorg` or `xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04` package is installed.

Comment: +1 for best answer *after* OP changed question.

Comment: I suggested the same in a comment even before OP clarified the question.

Comment: I had read your comment when it was first activity after thread was startled. Sorry I forgot to raise the comment then I'm bad with that. Rectified :)

Comment: Thanks. SEems to have fixed the problem.

But the scrolling got reversed, is there anyway to change it back to what it was?

I Don't want natural scrolling.

Comment: The scrolling should be normal, not "natural". It is possible to reverse it, but it seems that you used natural before.

Comment: The option is "NaturalScrolling". Try "true" and "false" to get what you want. "False" is the default.

Comment: @PIlot6 oh yeah, it seems I Was actually using natural scrolling, lol. had to enable it

Answer (score 9):

### For Ubuntu before 17.10 (Unity)

Open **System Settings** -> **Mouse & Touchpad** : in the Touchpad section switch from `ON` to `OFF`

[image]

Additional information for other users reading this post: The answer was written before the content of the question was changed, originally the question was: *"An actual solution to disable touchpad? I just want to disable the touchpad completely, no scrolling, no moving the cursor, nothing."*. So the [answer from @Pilot6](https://askubuntu.com/a/886098/349837) is the much better solution for what the current version of the question is asking about!

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I messed up the title. I want to disable the touchpad while typing, not disable it all the time.

Answer (score 7):

You can also do it with Synaptics.

```
synclient PalmDetect=1
```

That will not be permanent, but you can do this by creating or editing the following file and adding `Option "PalmDetect" "1"`

```
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier "touchpad"
  Driver "Synaptics"
    Option "PalmDetect" "1"
EndSection
```

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Disable_touchpad_while_typing

Answer (score 3):

In my eyes, palmdetect is not exactly "disable while typing", because this feature doesn't really consider what's happening on the keyboard. In my case, I don't permanently touch the pad while typing, so the detection didn't work properly. On the same link that HarlemSquirrel already [posted](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Disable_touchpad_while_typing), there's also a second solution which does exaclty what is requested (in the modified OP):

> Using syndaemon syndaemon monitors keyboard activity and disables the
>   touchpad while typing. It has several options to control when the
>   disabling occurs. View them with `$ syndaemon -h` For example, to disable tapping and scrolling for 0.5
>   seconds after each keypress (ignoring modifier keys like Ctrl), use

```
syndaemon -i 0.5 -t -K -R
```

> Once you have determined the options you
>   like, you should use your login manager or xinitrc to have it run
>   automatically when X starts. The -d option will make it start in the
>   background as a daemon.

Comment: I [confirmed](https://askubuntu.com/a/1151361/340383) that this is working on Ubuntu 19.04 LTS running the standard Gnome desktop.  This is with `synclient -l | grep PalmDetect` returning `PalmDetect              = 1` (which was enabled by default, not by my own changes). This implies, to me, that just having `synclient`'s `PalmDetect` set to 1 is not the solution, your answer is.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly when this feature was introduced, but in Ubuntu 20.20 LTS it's very simple.

In the search bar, search *Mouse and Touchpad*. Then select the *Touchpad* tab and check *Disable touchpad while typing*.

[image: Mouse and Touchpad Ubuntu]

That's all!

If you are quick or slow in typing you can also customize the *Duration*. That is how much seconds the trackpad will be disabled when you press a key. Set it lower if you are quick, upper if you are slow.

If you have not that option, try other answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to [How do I disable a touchpad using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67718/how-do-i-disable-a-touchpad-using-the-command-line) which recommends the synclient program.

If you have a Synaptics touchpad, then you can bind hotkeys to turn the pad off and on with

- `synclient TouchpadOff=1`
- `synclient TouchpadOff=0`

Comment: Does this answer the question regarding automatic "disable while typing" feature?

Comment: It doesn't do so automatically, but I've found it useful and doesn't require the addition of another package. Either way is good. Yours is automatic; mine while manual is also valid for the OP's question.