# Touchpad stopped working properly after system update

Tags: touchpad

I'm using ubuntu 16.04, after an update, my touchpad stopped working properly.

Tap to click no longer works, the cursor speed is lower than it was, and scrolling got reversed.

I was using `libinput` before the update, I had a problem and someone suggested to install it to fix the problem, and it did, https://askubuntu.com/a/886098/625501

I tried opening the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-libinput.conf` put I think it's messed up or something, I'm not sure.

[image: It looks like this]

I tried `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and then `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-libinput` but it says it's up to date.

Comment: Why did you post text as a picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-libinput.conf`

And add to the touchpad section after `Driver "libinput"`

```
Option "Tapping" "True"
Option "NaturalScrolling" "True"
```

Then log off and on. This will enable tapping and reverse scrolling.

Comment: Oh, that touchpad section, I Was looking at "Inputclass", thinking there was something wrong.

It works now, thank you. BUt the cursor speed is still slow.

Comment: You can adjust cursor speed too, but I am leaving now. Meanwhile you can ask "how to adjust cursor speed in libinput" as a new question. If nobody answers, I will look at it tonight.