# Text editing problems

Tags: 16.04

Whenever I edit in Vim or Nano or Firefox it sometimes or randomly jumps to some lines. This is actually kind of disturbing. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I don't know if anyone else has faced this problem.

Comment: Are you using a laptop? In that case, could it be that your palm is near or touching the touchpad? In that case you can disable the touchpad completely or partially. It is possible to use an alias or hotkey to turn it on/off quickly.

Comment: Yes iam using a Laptop. But just now using Firefox  when i was typing it scrolled down also the cursor skipped to 1st line :(

Comment: Are you using standard Ubuntu or a community flavour (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ...)? And what computer is it (brand name and model? -- The method to disable the touchpad depends on the operating system and computer (what kind of touchpad).

Comment: Iam using dell inspirion 5447 and os is ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Does it happen if you disable the touchpad? Try simply covering it with a piece of paper or a post it. If that's the issue, you can look into [disabling the touchpad while typing](https://askubuntu.com/q/886092/85695).

Comment: I tried the post it method  but in vain.

Comment: So it seems to be another problem. (You could try with a double or thicker paper to be sure.)

Comment: Tried with 4 post it.Just now it skipped.This happens especially when fast typing.

Comment: Have you got a separate USB keyboard? In that case you can check, if the same thing happens, when you use that keyboard. -- Also: Did this problem start, when you installed the system, or has it been working well and then suddenly, it started?

Comment: When i was typing in Google it skipped to next tab it seems(while typing).

Comment: You can **try with a newer or older version of Ubuntu**: Boot from a USB boot drive 'live', do not install, in order to find out if another linux kernel with its device drivers work better. -- Also, please **help us help you** by answering all our questions (at least let us know that you have seen the questions).

Comment: Should i install synaptics driver? Will it solve my problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66076/discussion-between-sudodus-and-b-b-m).