# How do I disable the touchpad in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: touchpad, 17.10

I recently updated to 17.10 from 17.04 and now I have no way to disable the touchpad on my laptop. When I do Fn + F9 (in my case), I see the touchpad logo in the screen as it where disabled, but is not.

ASUS GL752

Comment: I have used this solution and in works for me
https://askubuntu.com/questions/65951/how-to-disable-the-touchpad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem on my Asus X555UB, but I use the command
`synclient TouchpadOff=1` in @Legolas script. This works for me.
[source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67718/how-do-i-disable-a-touchpad-using-the-command-line)

Comment: I tried this code and it works for the touchpad only, but doesn't disable the buttons. Anyway it's much better and less annoying. Thank you!

Comment: works on my Thinkpad T520

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure why they key is not working for your laptop. But I can suggest a general alternative.

Put the following code in a file, such as `touchpad_toggle.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
STATUS=`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events`
if [ "$STATUS" = "'enabled'" ]
then
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events 'disabled'
else
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events 'enabled'
fi
```

Grant the file executable permission:

```
chmod +x touchpad_toggle.sh
```

Add a keyboard shortcut to the file from *Settings* → *Devices* → *Keyboard*.

Comment: has no effect on my thinkpad T520

Comment: #how to disable touchpad on 18.04 , works on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: works in Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 4):

Based on answers from Fernando and Legolas, here's a script that works for me:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
synclient -l | grep TouchpadOff | grep 1
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
  synclient TouchpadOff=0
else 
  synclient TouchpadOff=1
fi
```

Comment: I'm using a macbook pro and this seems to disable the mouse pointer moving, but doesn't block clicking or highlighting with the touchpad.  I guess there are another couple of settings needed for that.