# Touchpad works even though it seems disabled, Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, input-devices, xinput

I've got my laptop (Lenovo Y720) today. It got Windows pre-installed, and I installed Ubuntu 18.04 as dual boot.

I try to disable touchpad with <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f6</kbd>. I get the touchpad blocked image notification, but I can still move the cursor, click, drag. Just like it's activated.

Also, doesn't matter how many times I do <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f6</kbd>, it always shows "touchpad disabled".

How can I solve this issue? Thanks!

**Edit:** The command below disables the touchpad. How can I bind this to <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f6</kbd> shortcut?

```
xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Enabled" 0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable the touchpad in Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969851/how-do-i-disable-the-touchpad-in-ubuntu-17-10)

Comment: What's the output to  'synclient'

Comment: @Fabby "Couldnt find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?" sorry I was wrong. it gave the same on ToucpadOff=1 too.

Comment: Could you please run `xev -event keyboard`, focus its window, press and release Fn+F6 and [edit] your question to include the output? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Hi, there's the output: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/56YNPPM8WP/

Answer (score 1):

There's no key event for <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> which means that one cannot simply intercept and react to it through normal means.

Such vendor-specific function keys are often exposed through other means. For example, see if there are any kernel modules for you Laptop model, series, or vendor; those typically handle special keys. Unfortunately I know almost nothing about them beyond their existence.

Comment: Mehmet: What David is trying to tell you is: You cannot bind that to [Fn]+[F6] until the kernel gets updated and then it'll just start working...  Would [Ctrl][Alt][Shift][F6] to turn on and Ctrl][Alt][Shift][F7] to turn off be a possible workaround?

Comment: @Fabby: Excellent idea! Sorry for being a bit succinct. I was in a hurry to get back to my food when I wrote this…