# disabling touchpad via command as an on/off button

Tags: shortcut-keys, touchpad, xinput

Im trying to set a keyboard key to turn off touchpad. i noticed [How do I disable a touchpad using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67718/how-do-i-disable-a-touchpad-using-the-command-line), however all the commands feature a separate function to turn the touchpad on vs. off. How can you set up a single command to turn the touchpad on if it's off or off if it's on?

Comment: In my opinion, the link you have included in your question contains the answer. You want to be able to use same set of key(s) to toggle your touchpad on or off, right?

Comment: no just one key. so i need a single command. its the disable / enable touchpad button. @ManishKumarBisht

Answer (score 2):

This script should do it. Save it as `~/bin/toggle_touchpad.sh`, change the value of the `touchpad` variable to whatever your touchpad is called (see `xinput list`) and then map the script to your desired keyboard shortcut. Remember to make the script executable with `chmod a+x ~/bin/toggle_touchpad.sh`.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

## Change this value to whatever your touchpad is called
touchpad='SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'

status=$(xinput  list-props "$touchpad" | grep "Device Enabled" | gawk '{print $NF}');

if (( $status==1 )); then
    xinput -set-int-prop "$touchpad" "Device Enabled" 8 0
else
    xinput -set-int-prop "$touchpad" "Device Enabled" 8 1
fi
```